# CSS selectors and conditionals in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm trying to write a script in Ruby to parse a Wikipedia article using Nokogiri and CSS selectors. I'm a little confused about conditionals within the script though. Here's what I have so far (`page` is the downloaded html using Nokogiri):

```
page.css('h3').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end

page.css('li').each do |node|   
  if /\d|\D/.match(node)
    puts node.text.scan(/[\d]+\D*/).first
  end
end

page.css('td b').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

This all works fine. However, what I really want is something like this:

```
page.css('h3, li, td b').each do |node|
  # if it's an h3 node, do one thing
  # if it's a li node, do another thing
  # else if it's a 'td b' node, do another thing
end
```

This would allow the page to be parsed in order, instead of going through the body three separate times. However, I'm not sure how to write those conditionals within my script.

EDIT:
So now my script is

```
page.css('h3, li, td b').each do |node|
        case node.name
        when 'h3', 'b'
            puts node.text
        when 'li'
            if /\d|\D/.match(node)
                puts node.text.scan(/[\d]+\D*/).first
            end
        else
            next
    end
end
```

However, it hasn't changed the behavior. It processes them in the same order it did before (all the 'h3' elements, then all the 'li' elements, then all the 'b' elements).

EDIT 2:

Okay, I finally got it to work. Here was my final set of conditionals:

```
page.traverse do |node|
    case
            when 'h3' == node.name 
            puts node.text
        when 'li' == node.name 
            puts node.text.scan(/[\d]+\D*/).first if /\d|\D/.match(node)
        when 'b' == node.name
            puts node.text if (node.parent.name == 'p' or node.parent.name == 'td')
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: As noted by Mark below, there's absolutely nothing wrong with what you have right now, and leaving them separate is better than combining them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for traverse:

```
page.traverse do |node|
  case
    when ['h3', 'li'].include?(node.name) then puts node.text
    when 'b' == node.name && 'td' == node.parent.name then puts node.text[/\d+\D*/]
  end
end
```

Comment: Question: I'm getting everything I want, but I'm also getting random blank lines in my output. Can you think of any reason for this off the top of your head?

Comment: Hmm you might want to change it to: puts $1 if node.text[/\d+\D*/]

Comment: No luck. What is the $1 supposed to do?

Comment: It's just a shorter way to write your regex line. Try node.text.strip / $1.strip you've either got an extra newline or an empty text.

Answer (score 3):

With Nokogiri the page will not be parsed three separate times, even in your first scenario. Nokogiri parses the page once, creates an in-memory DOM, then uses the DOM to look up the nodes you want. It's not inefficient to perform multiple CSS or XPath lookups.

Nevertheless, if you still want to grab all nodes at once, you can do:

```
page.css('h3, li, td b').each do |node|
  case node.name
  when 'h3'
    do_something
  when 'li'
    do_something_else
  when 'b'
    do_another_thing
end
```

Note if you needed to differentiate between, say a `td b` and a `p b` then this technique won't work. I'd recommend separate lookups.

Comment: See my edit. Tried what you suggested without much luck (I don't think).

Comment: Ah, based on your edits I see you wanted to make sure they were processed in _document order_. My assumption was that you were concerned about the performance if it was re-parsing. @pguardiario has the answer you want.